# Is there a way to make the "o" keypress of other-window <C-x><C-o> repeatable?

Tags: window, commands, navigation

Question is as stated in the title.

Instead of using various packages for switching windows, it might be simpler to make `<C-x><C-o>` behave like `<C-x><C-+>`, such that repeated presses of the `o` key after the initial `<C-x><C-o>` will keep switching windows.

Comment: https://github.com/alphapapa/defrepeater.el looks like a general path to realize such requests as yours.  When I tried that out it refused to work occasionally.  Finally I stopped using it.  But I guess it's worth to be rediscovered.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a function similar to `text-scale-adjust`.  E.g.

```
(defun mw-other-window-repeat (count &optional all-frames)
  "Wrapper around `other-window' to continue to jump to other with key o."
  (interactive "p")
  (other-window count all-frames)
  (message "Use o to jump to next window.")
  (set-transient-map
   (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
     (define-key map (kbd "o")
       (lambda () (interactive) (mw-other-window-repeat 1)))
     map)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x o") #'mw-other-window-repeat)
```

> C-x ooooooo

has the desired effect AFAICS.  The repetition is over with another key press than o.

Answer (score 4):

I use this in several of my libraries. Use it to make pretty much any command repeatable even when it's on a prefix key.

```lisp
(defun repeat-command (command)
  "Repeat COMMAND."
  (require 'repeat)
  (let ((repeat-previous-repeated-command  command)
        (repeat-message-function           #'ignore)
        (last-repeatable-command           'repeat))
    (repeat nil)))
```

Then define a repeatable version of an existing command, such as `other-window`, just by passing that command to `repeat-command`. For example:

```lisp
(defun other-window-repeat ()
  "Select another window in cyclic ordering of windows.
This is a repeatable version of `other-window'."
  (interactive)
  (repeat-command 'other-window))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 4 o") 'other-window-repeat)
```

Answer (score 3):

hydra (https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra) are another way to get repeatable commands. This doesn't move the point on the first call, but you can press o as many times as you want to move around.

```
(defhydra other-window (:color red :body-pre (other-window 1))
  "other window"
  ("o" (other-window 1)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x o") #'other-window/body)
```

Comment: You can add `:body-pre (other-window 1)` to the hydra arguments to have it move the point on first call.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I only knew of :pre which runs before every head. I updated this solution with your suggestion!